# How to run python GUI using tkinter from nodered

Tags: python, tkinter, node-red

When i try to run a python file using EXEC from node red, it does work as long as it does not contain any GUI like tkinter.
the error on node red side when i try to execute is:
_tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no `$DISPLAY` environment variable

This is my Python file code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

l = Label(text="Hello world", font=("Helvetica",20))

l.pack()
```

Comment: You've not said how Node-RED is running. If it's running as a service then it will have no access to the X display  so you will not be able to start a program with a GUI

Answer (score 1):

add

```
mainloop( )
```

to the end of the python file and it should display the form.